# Facing issues while installing unmanaged package to other sandbox

Tags: unmanaged-package

I am trying to install Unmanaged package which include only some custom fields but during installation I am getting below error
[image]

I do not include any of the field whose duplicay is shown here. It is automatically taking all the response while adding custom fields to package.
Can anyone help me how can i resolve this as I am frustated now

Answer (score 0):

Though you have not added the fields manually when there is any sort of dependency the platform picks it up automatically. You can either try changing the field name in your destination org or the source org. If you are working in live instances then renaming the fields in source org is advisable.